# Is it possible to install and run docker inside node container in Jenkins?

Tags: node.js, docker, jenkins, docker-compose, jenkins-pipeline

This is somewhat complicated situation, but I have Jenkins installed inside a docker container. I'm trying to run some tests in node.js app, but this test environment requires docker+docker-compose to be enabled. At the moment, the Jenkins configuration is through pipeline code

So far, I've tried pulling docker inside a stage, as follow:

```
pipeline {
   agent  {
       docker {
           image 'node'
       }
   }
   stages {
       stage("Checkout") {
           steps {
            git url: ....
           }
       }
        stage("Docker") {
           steps {
               script {
                   def image = docker.image('docker')
                   image.pull()
                   image.inside() {
                      sh 'docker --version'
                      sh 'docker-compose --version'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

with error returning 'docker: not found'. I was expecting the script to succeed because I've tried exactly the same with 'agent any' which had no problem, but inside node image it doesn't seem to work.

I'm also not sure if this is the right way to do so because as I understand correctly, this way of running docker inside a docker is not recommended. One method that I have found is that when running docker, it is recommended to run `docker -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ...` but currently I am running on docker-compose, with installation steps from https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/docker/ (instead of individual docker, I've combined both jenkins and jenkins-blueocean into a docker-compose file), and that did not work.

At this moment, I'm out of idea and any solutions or other suggestions as to how to run both node.js and docker in the same environment, would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use docker-in-docker image https://hub.docker.com/_/docker